# Handling two different events on two different DOM element at the same time

Tags: jquery

I have a form which contains 4 accordions.Each accordion will have some input elements and a next button.

I will make an ajax call on change of each input element to validate it and when clicking the next button i ll check whether all the input elements are validated and show the next accordion.

So when someone changes an input field and click next button both onchange of input element and click of next button element get triggered but click event die sometimes without being executed due to the ajax call in onchange event take few swconds.

So in this particular scenario i want click event of next button to get triggered after the completion of onchange event of input field.

please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: Please, share some code with us...

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the execution of the next button so the ajax call can be completed